# anomaly detection using Paralel computing in R

Tags: r, doparallel

I have a data frame with more then 300mil rows and I want to detect anomaly in each group, which is consist of country and IDs (Each group) then I wrote the following code to detect anomaly points however it takes a lot time. Could you please suggest any other option that make it faster. The data frame format:

```
 df <- data.frame("id" = 1:n,"country"= ("US",..),"date"=("2021-01-01",..),"value"=c(10,....)) 


    registerDoParallel()
groupColumns <- c("country","id")
system.time(temp_anom <- ddply(df, groupColumns, function(x){
  x <- x[,c('date','value')]  
  resid.q <- quantile(x$value,prob = c(0.1,0.90))
  iqr <- diff(resid.q)
  limits <- resid.q + 3 * iqr * c(-1,1) 
  lower_bound <- limits[1]
  upper_bound <- limits[2]
  outlier_dip_index <- dplyr::filter(x, value < lower_bound) %>% data.frame() 
  if (nrow(outlier_dip_index) > 0) {
    outlier_dip_index$status <- "dip"}
  outlier_spike_index <- dplyr::filter(x, value > upper_bound) %>% data.frame()
  if (nrow(outlier_spike_index) > 0) {
    outlier_spike_index$status <- "spike"  
    outlier <- rbind(outlier_spike_index,outlier_dip_index)
    outlier
  }
},.paralle = T))
```

Answer (score 1):

For increasing the speed of parallel computing we need to ind the optimum number of cores in Doparallel, in this case the optimum is 5. only by modifying the code like below we can see tremendous  improvement in the seed.

```
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cores = 5)

system.time(temp_anom <- plyr::ldply(df$id, function(ids){
  title_dataset <- df[which(df$short_id == ids),]
  result_dataset <- plyr::ldply(title_dataset$country, function(iso){
    country_dataset <- title_dataset[which(title_dataset$country == iso),]
    resid.q <- quantile(country_dataset$raw_de, prob = c(0.1, 0.90))
    iqr <- diff(resid.q)
    limits <- resid.q + 3 * iqr * c(-1,1) 
    temp_dataset <- data.frame(country = iso, lower_bound = limits[1], upper_bound = limits[2])
    temp_dataset
  })
  result_dataset$id <- ids
  result_dataset
}, .parallel = T))
```